# GA Measurement Protocol: Site Search

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Is there a way to track search queries (site search) with the Measurement Protocol? I wasn't able to find it in the docs.

Comment: dl with a ?s= attached to it maybe don't know ever tried

Comment: dl specifies the [document location](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dl), not sure how this refers to site search

Comment: My guess is that sight search is just dl with s prossed by the server.    Kind of a guess as it's not an option you can send.   I may test it myself just out of curiosity.

Comment: got it, thanks. Already testing it and waiting that it will show up in GA. Will post feedback as soon as I the request in site search

Comment: It works as you suggested, thanks a lot

Comment: Great question really never thought about it before.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the dl (document location) and add   ?s=   it should detect it as search